# C# internal types in protected fields

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, encapsulation

I am trying to write a class library as following:

```
namespace Test
{
    class Field
    { 
    }

    public abstract class SomeClass
    {
        protected Field field;  //Inconsistent accessibility: field type 'Field' is less accessible than field 'SomeClass.field'
    }

    public class SomeDerivedClass1:SomeClass
    {
    }

    public class SomeDerivedClass2:SomeClass
    {
    }
}
```

Rules:

1. I do not want to make `Field` a protected subclass of `SomeClass`, because it is used by other classes;
2. I do not want to make `Field` visible outside of `Test` namespace, because it's breaks encapsulation;
3. I need inheritance, because `SomeDerivedClass1` and `SomeDerivedClass2` share a lot of code.

Is any workaround for this problem without breaking any of these rules?

Comment: There is no way to make `Field` visible only to a specific namespace. Namespaces don't encapsulate anything anyway. The purpose of namespaces is to prevent naming collisions.

Comment: But `Field` is encapsulated within `Test` if it's `private`

Comment: No it isn't. It won't compile if it's private. Go ahead and try it

Comment: Yeah, namespace members can't be private, I missed that one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [new `private protected` modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/private-protected). This is the equivalent of `internal` AND `protected`.

> Not to be confused with `protected internal` which is `protected` OR `internal`

```cs
public abstract class SomeClass
{
    private protected Field field;
}
```

It is still visible in the same assembly outside the namespace though.

Comment: It still will be available outside of `Test` in the same assembly. But, I guess, it's the best one can achieve...